# VueJS: Input checkboxes and toggling div elements

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a form with checkboxes that, when selected, will reveal a div on the page with some secondary action information for the user. Each checkbox has its own special div with more information.

However, I have 2 checkboxes that contain the same instructions and the issue is that when both are selected, 2 instances of the instructions appear.

**How would I write the conditional logic so only one set of instructions is shown if both of those checkboxes are selected by the user?**

Here's a live demo of the issue: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/bLt53qrg/)

Scenario:

Select *DEF -->CUSTOM STATIC GRAPHIC SUPPORT and CUSTOM ANIMATION SUPPORT and you'll notice how two copies of "Fill out the custom graphic support here" elements are shown at the bottom of the page.*

> Snipped HTML:

```
        <label for="custom_static_graphic">
          <input type="checkbox" id="custom_static_graphic" value="Custom Static Graphic" v-model="selectedProducts">Custom Static Graphic Support
        </label>

        <label for="custom_animation">
          <input type="checkbox" id="custom_animation" value="Custom Animation Support" v-model="selectedProducts">Custom Animation Support
        </label>
```

> My attempt to write like-so did not work:

```
 <div class="alert alert-success" v-if="(!selectedOffice.inJira) && ( (product ==='Custom Animation Support') || (product === 'Custom Static Graphic') )">Fill out the custom graphic support here</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking the div outside the loop.